# Communication between fragments android using EventBus

Tags: android, observer-pattern, event-bus

Requirement:
FragmentA contains list --- user can mark any item favorite/unfavorite.
On marking favorite, icon will be marked red in fragmentA and item should appear in FavoriteFragment.
 **( Achieved this using EventBus )**

Similarly, marking any item as unfavorite from FavoriteFragment should remove from FavoriteFragment and FragmentA icon will be marked as Green (Resolution required for this)

have tried to EventBus.getDefault().register(this); in both fragments fragmentA and FavoriteFragment
but when post both of the fragments **onMessageEvent** called.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(List<Event> result) {
}
```

Comment: I didn't catch you question about EventBus, but your approach is not good enough, first of all using EventBus will make code harder to understand and debug, second: you should apply favorite and unfavorite changes locally in your db then in favorite fragment get all of them from `Room` db with `LiveData`

Answer (score 1):

Add EventBus to your project via Gradle

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Data Modal (Data.java)

```
public class Data {
    private List<Boolean> markList;

    public List<Boolean> getMarkList() {
        return markList;
    }

    public void setMarkList(List<Boolean> markList) {
        this.markList = markList;
    }
}
```

Source Fragment (FragmentA.java)

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

     private void sendDataToFavorit(){
         List<Boolean> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
         selectedList.add(true);  // index 0
         selectedList.add(false); // index 1

         Data data = new Data();
         data.setMarkList(selectedList);

         EventBus.getDefault().post(data);
     }
}
```

Destination Fragment (FavoriteFragment.java)

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {
     private Context context;

     public FavoriteFragment () {           
         // Register your subscriber in constructor     
         EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         // UnRegister your subscriber in onDestroy
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }


    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(@NonNull Data data) {
        // Get data from FragmentA
        List<Boolean> markList = data.getMarkList();
        if (markList != null && markList.size()>0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < markList.size(); i++) {
                Log.i("LOG", "list " + i + ": " + markList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for code sharing, this integration and code done but the only issue was to integrate 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

Add id of the item when you populate you list  and use sqlite database. 
save id of the item when its checked or uncheck . when you populate your list check for that id if its match make it red.
Hope it will help